# Regex: Remove the functions and variables of the tag <script type> so to keep the text

Tags: javascript, regex

Good day. Maybe someone helps me a little bit. I have this tag/script code with a lot of variables from a Blogspot website. But in the code, there is a phrase that I want to keep: "I LOVE THE WAY YOU LOOK AT ME".

So I need to delete all content of this tag, to keep only that phrase.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    (function() {
       var items = [{'id': '7357108209166779288', 'body': 'I LOVE THE WAY YOU LOOK AT ME', 'timestamp': '1344632698483', 'permalink': 'http://a-lot-of-dreams.blogspot.com/2012/08/love-from-aurora.html?showComment/x3d1344632698483#c7357108209166779288', 'author': {'name': 'S.', 'avatarUrl': 'beautiful%2Bface.png'/*tpa=http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-8XQRrzbAAZM/T7dnJP1bEVI/AAAAAAAAASw/wHBbf1EXyxs/s35/beautiful%25252Bface.png*/, 'profileUrl': 'https://www.blogger.com/profile/17938221881634050545'}, 'displayTime': '11 august 2012, 00:04', 'deleteclass': 'item-control blog-admin pid-1087087483'}];
       var msgs = {'loadMore': 'Încărcați mai multe...', 'loading': 'Se încarcă...', 'loaded': 'Gata!', 'addComment': 'Adăugați un comentariu', 'reply': 'Răspundeți', 'delete': 'Ștergere'};
       var config = {'blogId': '2543786116189513218', 'postId': '155575719554183698', 'feed': 'http://a-lot-of-dreams.blogspot.com/feeds/155575719554183698/comments/default', 'authorName': 'Duduş', 'authorUrl': 'https://www.blogger.com/profile/01529949428387452289', 'baseUri': 'https://www.blogger.com', 'maxThreadDepth': 2};
       var cursor = null;
       if (items && items.length > 0) {
           cursor = parseInt(items[items.length - 1].timestamp) + 1;
       } 
</script>
```

My desire output:

> I LOVE THE WAY YOU LOOK AT ME

I try a regex but is not very good.

> Search: `(('body')(.*?)('timestamp'))|((<script[\s\S]*?(</script>)[\s\S]*?))\1`
>
> Replace by: `$1`

Comment: Why does it matter if the type `type='text/javascript'` is there ?

Comment: You can get the tag contents in group 1, then check it there `<(?:(?:(?:script(?:\s+(?>"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+)?\s*>)([\S\s]*?)</script\s*(?=>)))>` or you can insert your search string specifically. Here, replace by `$1`, regex `<(?:(?:(?:script(?:\s+(?>"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+)?\s*>)(?:(?!</script\s*>)[\S\s])*?(I\ LOVE\ THE\ WAY\ YOU\ LOOK\ AT\ ME)[\S\s]*?</script\s*(?=>)))>`

Comment: hello Sin, pls check again. Doesn't work any of your regex at my place

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer, maybe someone will give a better regex.

> `((<script type)[\s\S]*?('body')[\s\S]*?|(var msgs)[\s\S]*?(</script>)[\s\S]*?)|(var msgs)[\s\S]*?([}];)[\s\S]*?|(('timestamp')[\s\S]*?('body')[\s\S]*?|('timestamp')[\s\S]*?(blog-admin)[\s\S]*?)|[:,;'}{\]\[]|pid-\d+`